# Trigger click event dynamically in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8

Tried to trigger click event for element reference based on index but not working in angular 8.If anyone know please help to find solution.

app.component.html:

```
        <div class="st-item" *ngFor="let data of datalist; let i = index">
            <input type="radio" name="st" id="{{data.name}}" />
            <label for="{{data.name}}" #items (click)="showproduct(data.name)">
                <span>
                    {{data.display}}
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  @ViewChildren('items') liItems: QueryList<ElementRef>

  ngOnInit(){ 
    const indexItem = 2; 
    this.liItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (index === (indexItem - 1)) (item.nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();
    }); 
  }
```

console.log(this.liItems);
[image]

Comment: Did you check if `liItems` does even have any items? ngFor under the hood creates `ng-template` so probably `#items` element lives only in ngFor body. Additionally you can't mark multiple elements with `#items`, try to rather get the items eg. with class name

Comment: @ThaFog: How to get the class name?Can you edit my code?

Comment: @ThaFog: Can you answer for this question? sixtwo49843nine

Comment: @PappaS Why do you need to trigger click, do you just want to have radio with given index selected?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't get any error in the console then I don't know what happened but 2 things I see is wrong there:

- `ngOnInit` is being called directly after component init but view is not always finished before this call. In this case you should try `ngAfterViewInit` or `ngAfterContentInit` to be sure `ngFor` and whole view is rendered. You didn't say where you called `console.log(this.liItems)` but calling it in this case in `ngOnInit` and getting anything than `undefined` would be weird
- In case you get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` try to encapsulate your code in `setTimeout` function

Let me know if there will be any new errors or you didn't get around with. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can check article related to it, may be you will found solution here.

https://dev.to/gloriamaris/how-to-programmatically-trigger-click-event-in-angular-4--3i6a

Note: I know this very late reply to this question, but may be this is helpful for someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).